# Callback of ion-google-place auto complete select

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I don't have much experiences with Ionic, however I am trying to build something like search for places and center the map based on selection.
I found ion-google-place quite useful when it comes to searching for location, but I wish to have callback function or something similar(ng-change?) so that I can center the map based on selection.

Is there any way for me to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-change` like so:

```
<ion-google-place data-ng-model="model" ng-change="update()" />
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.update = function() {
    console.log('hello callback');
}
```